# Error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm running this query:

```
select sm.stockid as 'id',description as 'descripcion',price as 'precio'
from stockmaster as 'sm', prices as 'pc' 
where 
sm.stockid=pc.stockid and
sm.stockid='ESPOLVOREO' and 
curdate() between pc.startdate and pc.enddate;
```

And I keep getting this error, I don't kwon why :/

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''sm', prices as 'pc' where sm.stockid=pc.stockid and sm.stockid='ESPOLVOREO' a' at line 2
```

I'm running the query directly on the db.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the table alias in quotes.

```
from stockmaster as sm, prices as pc
```

Comment: Who said that alias can not be in quotes? :) Off. manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html What i'm missing?

Comment: The alias cannot be in single quotes. The usual quote character is the backtick. You can use double quotes, but only if you have enabled ANSI_QUOTES.

Comment: `SELECT 1 AS one, 2 AS 'two';` from official manual, I think it enabled by default. (change answer about single quotes)

Comment: The error is with the table alias, not with the column alias.

Comment: Oh, i see, but anyway it won't solve his trouble, because next error will be on column alias...

Comment: It worked, column alias allowed me to use single quotes, but table alias didn't.

Comment: @user1954544, nothing is wrong with the column aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
description as 'descripcion', price as 'precio'
```

change to

```
sm.description as 'descripcion', sm.price as 'precio'
```

regarding table you need (added table name before column name).

Comment: If this was the problem you the database would complain about an ambiguous column in field list. The error message in this case shows a generic syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as user3456640 states, don't write your aliases with quotes.

```
SELECT sm.stockid AS id, description AS descripcion, price AS precio
```

Secondly, Your missing some aliasses in the calls. Should look like this.

```
SELECT sm.stockid AS id,
sm.description AS descripcion,
pc.price AS precio
FROM stockmaster AS sm, prices AS pc 
where 
sm.stockid=pc.stockid AND
sm.stockid='ESPOLVOREO' AND 
curdate() BETWEEN pc.startdate AND pc.enddate;
```